# How does \pgfdecoratedpathlength work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am trying to understand how it works the decoration pgf module, in order to solve the unanswered question [Fiber-Optic-Style decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149541/fiber-optic-style-decoration?noredirect=1#comment339991_149541).

I am having an hard time with some macros, for example `\pgfdecoratedpathlength`. Look the following MWE, from what I read on the pgfmanual version 2.10, the options (1), (2) and (3) should be equivalent, but only (2) works, while I get 100 errors for the others.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfsys,pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows,decorations,snakes}


\pgfdeclaredecoration{fiber}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        switch if less than=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2 to final %% (1)
        %width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2 %% (2)
        %width=.5\pgfdecoratedpathlength %% (3)
        ]{
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{15pt}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{-15pt}}
    }
    \state{final}{
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={fiber, amplitude=1cm}, draw=red]
\draw[->,decorate] (3, 5mm) -- ++(4,0); %% ERROR! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgf@decorate@width
\draw[->,decorate] (3,0)    -- ++(3,0);
\draw[->,decorate] (3,-5mm) -- ++(2,0);
\draw[->,decorate] (3,-1cm) -- ++(1,0);
\draw[->,decorate] (3,-1.5cm) -- ++(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first error is `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgf@decorate@width` , in the first draw. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a TeX length but just a macro hence `0.5*\dimen` should work instead of `.5\dimen` (not tested)

Comment: `width=.5*\pgfdecoratedpathlength` works for (3) in place of `width=.5\pgfdecoratedpathlength`. But why (1) does not work? By the manual, (1) and (2) should be completely equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the comma after `final`. So `width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2` is dropped and Ti*k*Z questioned that how come the width is not defined???

The following code works fine.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{fiber}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[
        switch if less than=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2 to final, %% (1)
        width=\pgfdecoratedpathlength/2 %% (2)
        ]{
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{15pt}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{-15pt}}
    }
    \state{final}{
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={fiber, amplitude=1cm}, draw=red]
        \draw[->,decorate] (3, 5mm) -- ++(4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]